# flyway : Unsupported Database: MySQL 8.0

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-mvc, flyway

I am using java 11, and I have added flyway in spring-boot application like below.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.29'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '2.7.0'
    implementation group: 'org.flywaydb', name: 'flyway-core', version: '8.5.13'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

and added properties as

```
# flyway
spring.flyway.baseline-on-migrate=true
spring.flyway.enabled=false
#spring.flyway.enabled=true
spring.flyway.locations=classpath:db/migration
```

but it is producing an error that, `org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unsupported Database: MySQL 8.0`

[image: Output]

Answer (score 69):

You should add flyway-mysql dependency.

**Maven :**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-mysql</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**Gradel:**

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.flywaydb:flyway-mysql"
}
```

More information [here](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/database/mysql#java-usage).

Answer (score 6):

The only way that worked for me was to add these dependencies to build.gradle:

```
implementation 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core:8.4.4'
implementation 'org.flywaydb:flyway-mysql:8.4.4'
```

As shown [here](https://www.code4copy.com/java/spring-boot-flyway-db-migration-integration-example/)

Answer (score 0):

For using Flyway you to create a Flayway bean:

Attached exmaple code:

```
import org.flywaydb.core.Flyway;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.r2dbc.R2dbcProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(FlywayProperties.class)
public class FlywayDatabaseConfig {

    @Bean(initMethod = "migrate")
    public Flyway flyway(FlywayProperties flywayProperties) {
        return Flyway.configure()
                .dataSource(
                        flywayProperties.getUrl(),
                        flywayProperties.getUser(),
                        flywayProperties.getPassword()
                )
                .locations(flywayProperties.getLocations().toArray(String[]::new))
                .baselineOnMigrate(true)
                .load();
    }

}
```

Comment: Answers that contain only code are generally considered poor quality. Can you [edit] your answer and provide some explanation as to how this code solves the problem described in the posted question?