# flyway-ant: No database found to handle jdbc:

Tags: ant, flyway

I'm trying to set up an ant build calling some of the flyway-ant targets, but I always end up with build failures saying

```
Flyway Error: No database found to handle jdbc:mariadb://<some_host>:3306/<some_db>
```

or similar (different JDBC URLs, depending on configuration). In build.xml, I'm referencing a fat jar which definitely contains all classes from flyway-core, flyway-mysql, flyway-ant and various JDBC driver packages, including mariadb, mysql and others:

```
<path id="tools.lib.classpath" location="path/to/my/fat.jar" />

<path id="flyway.lib.path" refid="tools.lib.classpath" />
<path id="flyway.classpath" >
    <pathelement path="path/to/my/sql/migrations"/>
    <path refid="tools.lib.classpath"/>
</path>
<taskdef uri="antlib:org.flywaydb.ant" resource="org/flywaydb/ant/antlib.xml" classpathref="flyway.lib.path" />

<target name="db-info">
    <property name="flyway.url" value="jdbc:mariadb://<some_host>:3306/<some_db>" />
    <property name="flyway.user" value="some_user" />
    <property name="flyway.password" value="psst!" />
    <flyway:info/>
</target>
```

The exception has its origin in flyway's org.flywaydb.core.internal.database.DatabaseTypeRegister, where obviously no DatabaseType can be found for MariaDB URLs. (Same problem when using a MySQL URL instead.)

The same flyway setup (same maven packages used like in the fat jar, same jdbc URL) works fine, though, when used from within the actual application under development.

I'm on flyway 8.5.13 (as version-managed by Spring Boot) and flyway-ant 2.19.3.

Any ideas?

Comment: I add the same issue and this post below helped me
[flyway-database-mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72711770/flyway-unsupported-database-mysql-8-0)

Answer (score 2):

OK, got it: Flyway's database adapters are provided and loaded as "services" in `org.flywaydb.core.internal.plugin.PluginRegister` through a call to `ServiceLoader.load(Plugin.class, CLASS_LOADER)`. In both the `flyway-core` and the `flyway-mysql` packag, the services are defined in a file called `META-INF\services\org.flywaydb.core.extensibility.Plugin`, and since my fat jar contained only the former, the MariaDB adapter was not detected.
Since it is virtually impossible for a jar to contain two files sharing the same path, I guess I'll have to reconsider my project's packaging... But anyway, mystery solved! :)

Comment: Thank you @torsten-crass! Was pulling my hair out trying to figure out why it didn't work in a fat jar, but works in my dev environment!

The solution was to add an assembly rule to specifically do an "append" against the `META-INF\services\org.flywaydb.core.extensibility.Plugin` file (with a "\n" separator) when creating a fat jar. This will depend on your build tool and how configurable that is.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and got it resolved with

You should add flyway-mysql dependency.

```
Maven :

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-mysql</artifactId>
</dependency>

Gradel:

dependencies {
    compile "org.flywaydb:flyway-mysql"
}
```

For more detail: [flyway-database-mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72711770/flyway-unsupported-database-mysql-8-0)